# Is it possible to use draggable items in Wordpress Gutenberg Editor?

Tags: wordpress, draggable, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a problem with draggable items inside Gutenberg Editor in custom blocks. Is it possible at all?

I tried to use **draggable prop** and **Draggable component**. Nothing works.

Draggable attribute:

```
<div draggable></div>
```

or

```
<div draggable="true"></div>
```

or example from https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/draggable

Devtools shows draggable attribute (draggable="true"), but I still can't drag any items inside the editor. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your code?
Are you including 
`import { Draggable } from '@wordpress/components';` like example does?

Comment: I'm struggling with this. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use draggable items in Gutenberg with the Draggable component, however the `<Draggable>` component is/was only intended to work within the `<InspectorControls>` and not within the main block editing interface, ref: [GitHub Issue 12635](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12635)

The example code from [WordPress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/draggable/#usage) shows a draggable component inside a Panel/PanelBody, which is used within `<InspectorControls>`. The draggable component could change as Gutenberg is still in active development. I also found the [source code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/components/src/draggable/) useful to better understand how this component works.